# MySQL + PHP select all rows who has a date between today and two weeks ahead

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a MySQL table that looks something like this:

```
+-----+------------+
| id  | enddate    |
+------------------+
| 1   | 2012-06-30 |
+------------------+
| 2   | 2012-07-05 |
+------------------+
| 3   | 2012-07-02 |
+------------------+
```

On my website I would like to print out all rows who has a date that is between the range:
*Today's date* (I mean not fixed, but the date when the query is beeing run) and *2 weeks ahead*.
So, using the above example only row 1 and 3 would be printed.
Anyone got a solution for this?

Comment: When downvoting please explain WHY you do it, especially for new users who may not be familiar with the SO system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need the BETWEEN comparison operator and some simple date functions:

```
WHERE enddate BETWEEN CURDATE() AND ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY);
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
WHERE enddate BETWEEN CURDATE() AND ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK);
```

[`Reference`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)